# IP logging on registration?

Tags: authentication, ip

I want to limit the use of a registered account to the household/ shop/ office where it was registered.

I was thinking logging the IP and checking on each login attempt to see if it matches.

Will this limit the user to logging in on 1 computer only though? as this is not what I want; whether the office/ shop/ household has 1 or 100 computers, they all need to be able to use the same login.

any other suggestions on how best to do this would be great!

Comment: This won't work, in general.  A user's IP address can change.

Comment: hmm I see. Is there any other way to achieve a similar result? Basically I would like to stop a large company getting 1 login, and letting all of its outlets using it when in reality, each outlet should have its own login

Comment: The IP your application sees will most likely be the IP of the company's firewall, so everyone at the company has the same IP. And for normal users, their IP will change if they take their laptop/tablet to a Starbucks.